# Failed to authenticate SIP peer

Tags: voip, sip, asterisk

I am trying to connect an SIP peer using Zoiper to my asterisk server. The peer is a soft-phone on my server. I have the following config for the peer:

```
[201]
disallow=all
allow=alaw
host=192.168.1.180
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
secret=apassword
type=peer
context=incoming-internal
canreinvite=no
qualify=yes
nat=no
srtpcapable=no
encryption=no
```

When I do not use `host=dynamic` the peer is reachable. However, when I go to make a call I get:

Zoiper gives a `SIP 403 -Forbidden error, bearer capability not authorized` and Asterisk gives:

```
NOTICE[17637]: chan_sip.c:23540 handle_request_invite: Failed to authenticate device <sip:201@192.168.1.180;transport=UDP>;tag=81635b62
```

When I put the configuration to `host=dynamic` the peer connects and then becomes unreachable. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `type=peer` to `type=friend` make a `sip reload` and try again.

SIP clients must use `type=friend` to let them be able to authenticate, receive and and send calls.

Comment: I changed it. Now I'm getting `Registration from <sip...> failed for 192.168.1.180:33820- Peer is not suppose to register ` This happens when I try to create a Zoiper account for the peer. When I do dynamic, I get the Host is my router's public ip and that it is unreachable.

Comment: Are Asterisk and Zoiper client on the same LAN or is there a NAT between them?

Comment: They are on the same machine. So no NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I did following changes:
nat=yes
and
made sure the Zoiper used udp and STUN